# Mimic an interrupt without activating an interrupt

Tags: c, assembly, interrupt

Is it possible to mimic the actions of an interrupt without activating the interrupt.

The reason why I ask is because the micro controller I am using only allows one interrupt to me active at any given time. As I am creating a time triggered system, I have already got an interrupt set up for the timer.

Basically I have to create a TT system (time triggered) so functions are deployed periodically. I am creating a data logging system, so character come in from the UART and are stored and recorded. I need to have an interrupt for the serial port, which will occur when a character comes in from the user. So I need to design a system which has two interrupts, one for the timer and one for the serial port. However the controller does not allow two interrupt active at the same time.

I am really sorry if this is confusing, I have posted a link to the datasheet to the controller and here is my code for the interface

```
void Menu_Update(void)
{
    uint8_t x=010;
    char i;
    i= (char)x;
    // Perform an appropriate action based on the current state.
    //Disable_Interrupt();
    //Enable_System_Interrupt(UART1);
    timer_count++;
    switch (menu_state)
    {
    case MAIN_MENU :
        // Output the initial menu choices and move to the wait state.
        Serial_UART_Write_String("Waiting for character input.......\r\n");
        Serial_UART_Write_String("To view data, enter 'a' \r\n");
        menu_state = MENU_WAIT ;
        break;
    case MENU_2:
        Serial_UART_Write_String("\r\nWould you also like to store this character as well?\r\n");
        Serial_UART_Write_String("Yes Enter 'y' \r\n");
        Serial_UART_Write_String("No Enter 'n' \r\n");
        menu_state = MENU_WAIT ;
        break;
    case MENU_WAIT :
        // Do nothing unless user input was detected.
    default:
        if (Serial_UART_Received_Data())
        {
            const char value = Serial_UART_Read();
            temp = value;
            Serial_UART_Write_String("\r\n***Character: ");
            Serial_UART_Write_Char(value);
            Serial_UART_Write_String(" has been received***\r\n");
            if (value == 'a'||menu_check==1)
            {
                menu_check =1;
                if (value == 'y')
                {
                    menu_check =0;
                    menu_state = WRITE_CHAR;
                }
                if (value == 'n')
                {
                    Serial_UART_Write_String("\r\nSegment format -> ");
                    Serial_UART_Write_String("Character count.Time\r\n");
                    menu_check =0;
                    menu_state = DISPLAY;
                }
                if (menu_check==1)
                {
                menu_state = MENU_2;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                menu_state = WRITE_CHAR;
            }
        }
        break;
    case WRITE_CHAR:
        character_array_storage[character_count]=temp;
        charac_time = timer_count - ref_timer;
        timer_interval_array[character_count]=charac_time;
        character_count++;
        Serial_UART_Write_String("\r\n***Character Stored***\r\n");
        menu_state = MAIN_MENU;
        break;
    case DISPLAY:
        assign_value(character_count,charac_time);
        Serial_UART_Write_String("\r\n***Segments Updated***\r\n");
        menu_state = MAIN_MENU;
        break;
    }
    //Disable_Interrupt();
    //Enable_System_Interrupt(TIMER0);
}
void Enable_System_Interrupt(const uint32_t int_source)
{
    Status_Reg_Set((Status_Reg_Get()& 0xFFFFF8FF) | (int_source << 8));
}
void Status_Reg_Set(uint32_t value)
{
    __asm volatile("mtc0 %0, $12" :: "d" ((unsigned long)(value)));

}
```

[Datasheet](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http://www.tte-systems.com/downloads/tte32_hr2_lite_data_prog.pdf&ei=eOB7UPXYJoGu0QWXxIHgDA&usg=AFQjCNHp2vWU-OowYlIbkV1xTocmDF2vjQ&sig2=Bqkamt38BVQzA_PHSML3AQ)
Thank you

Comment: How do you mean? How to call the interrupt handler from your standard code?

Comment: unclear question, give some more details on the specification (what does your program should do), or insert some code pls

Comment: @slugonamission The OP's hardware can only receive interrupts from one (1) device. You can choose which one, but it's going to be only one. The OP wants to simulate interrupts from other devices, as if the h/w could receive interrupts from multiple devices. So, as I understand it, he would assign the timer to that 1 interrupt and inside the timer ISR would check the state of other devices and if needed invoke their ISRs.

Comment: @ern0 See my comment above, it should clarify things. I skimmed the datasheet a day or two ago when a related question was asked (but then disappeared).

Comment: Note that the timer rate should be higher than the character rate of the UART, or some received characters may get lost/overwritten by newer ones if they are coming in without delays between them.

Comment: Alexey i think i understand your explaination, so basically i need to have a master interrupt on one device which will sync the other devices and i could implement the uart interrupt on the slave device, is my understanding of what you said correct??

Comment: Maybe as I'm not entirely sure what is meant by "the slave device", is it the one that can't generate interrupts? On a second thought, I don't think you actually need to make a normal ISR for the UART. The timer ISR will save and restore the context of the interrupted code (registers and what not). Just make the UART ISR a normal function and call it directly from the timer ISR without messing with simulation of an interrupt. In that function examine the state of the UART receiver and transmitter to determine if there's data available or more data can be sent.

Comment: Yes the slave device will not generate the interrupt, when u say make the uart isr a normal function, could you possibly explain that a bit further, as i am to believe having the uart isr as a normal function, thats not an interrup and i would be making time triggered hybrid system, which i shouldnt be doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this if you know assembler of your microprocessor well enough. Check your docs, but for 90% of CPUs it is enough to push into the stack current status word before making the call to the interrupt handler. In this case it will successfully return using its `iret` instruction.

At the end of the day interrupt handler is the same function except that it preserves more registers and at the end execute `iret` instead of ordinary `ret`.